# Regex string for different versions

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to isolate instances in a Pandas Dataframe where the version number is not equal to .0 —i.e., if there are versions 10.0, 10.1, and 10.2, I only want to select versions 10.1 and 10.2. Does anyone know the proper regex to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: can you add a sample of your dataframe ?

Comment: Apologies, @TrentonMcKinney...I just got back to my computer a little while ago. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @ClaytonCohn glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)
- Split the string on the `.` and look at the value at index 1
- It's not clear if this is a column of `str` or `float` types.

  - If the column is `str` type, remove `.astype(str)`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'versions': [10.0, 10.1, 10.2, 10.19]})

 versions
    10.00
    10.10
    10.20
    10.19

df_f = df[df.versions.astype(str).str.split('.', expand=True)[1] != '0']

 versions
    10.10
    10.20
    10.19
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern `r'\b\d+.0\b'` with `str.contains` to create boolean mask using for slicing out `.0` strings. It only slices out `.0` and keeps `.00` as in the output

sample df:

```
  version
0    10.5
1    10.2
2    10.0
3     9.0
4    9.18
5   10.00

m = df.version.str.contains(r'\b\d+.0\b')
df[~m]

Out[54]:
  version
0    10.5
1    10.2
4    9.18
5   10.00
```